# In PHP: if a matching case is found, are any of the remaining case statements evaluated?

Tags: php, optimization, switch-statement, control-structure

I have a switch statement in a tight loop that looks like this:

```
switch(true) {
    case /*expensive comparison */:
    case /*another expensive comparison */:
    case /*different expensive comparison */:
        return true;
}
return false;
```

I looking to see if any of the expensive comparisons is true, but only one. I know there are other ways to accomplish this, but this one looks nice and clean. The real question is: if `expensive comparison` evaluates to true, does it also run `another expensive comparison` also, or just jump to the return?

**EDIT:**
I realize this could be accomplished with a simple or statement, but now I want to know for theory's sake.

```
return /*expensive comparison */
         || /*another expensive comparison */
         || /*different expensive comparison */;
```

Comment: No it won't re-evaluate each subsequent comparison even when it's found one

Comment: @Mark Baker: so it does stop checking cases after one matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had a chance to do some testing on this, and it looks like it (5.4 at least) stops evaluating cases once one matches. Here is how I verified that:

```
<?php
function evaluate($id)
{
    echo $id, "\n";
    return true;
}

switch (true) {
    case evaluate(1):
    case evaluate(2):
    case evaluate(3):
    echo "Evaluated\n";
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 >1
 >Evaluated
```

Answer (score 2):

yes,

They are run until a break is hit. the cases below the matching one are all run regardless if they match

```
<?php
$i =0;
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i equals 0";
    case 1:
        echo "i equals 1";
    case 2:
        echo "i equals 2";
}
?>
```

would show all 3 echos for example

Switch statements are designed to compare 1 value to many conditions. So no once it has the match it will be optimized not to look for any more.

Comment: This does not answer my question--I know that it executes statements until a break; the issue is whether it evaluates additional cases. I could not find an answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will execute statements from all other subsequent cases if no break is used, irrelevant of whether the cases match:

```
switch(1)
{
    case 1:
            echo 1;
    case 2:
            echo 2;
    case 3:
            echo 3;

    return 'done';
}
```

Output: 123

"...PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case."

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Please see the comment on user1281385's post

Comment: OK, I believe I understand your question now.  From my experience, it does not actually evaluate the other cases.  Just tested this with the code included in answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code with the switch as shown (without any breaks in it) will evaluate all of them.  As far as I can recall, the || syntax will only do the comparison if the preceding evaluation is false.

On the other hand, it wouldn't take much to take a case structure and make it behave the same as the || syntax and would make for easier to read code.

Either way, the answer to this is pretty easy to acquire with just a simple test.  Just echo or errorlog out something for each comparison.  It is best to try and figure things out yourself before you go asking questions on a site like this.

See [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) for why.